# SHA256 mismatch error when trying brew install azd

Tags: azure, homebrew

I am trying to install Azure Developer cli on my mac (M1 chip).

However I running into SHA256 error:

```
Error: azd: SHA256 mismatch
Expected: *****************************
  Actual: *****************************
    File: /Users/././***--azd-darwin-amd64.zip
To retry an incomplete download, remove the file above.
```

I do have Rosetta installed on my machine.

The code I used to install azd:

```
brew tap azure/azd && brew install azd
```

Any azure folks out there running into this issue?
Any guide on fixing this is helpful

Comment: Did you ever figure how to resolve this issue? Facing exactly the same on M1 mac

Comment: @DanielFlippance unfortunately not!

Answer (score 1):

***This error could be due to the downloaded file is corrupted or not downloaded properly:***

**Follow below steps:**

1. Remove the downloaded file `azd-darwin-amd64.zip` using the below command:

   ```
   rm /Users/././***--azd-darwin-amd64.zip
   ```
2. Run the below commands to *clean and update* ***brew***:

   ```
   brew cleanup
   brew update
   ```
3. Then, try running the installation command again:

   ```
   brew tap azure/azd && brew install azd
   ```
4. Verify the installation by running the following command:

   ```
   azd --version
   ```

Comment: I have Rosetta installed and have run your suggested steps but still have the `SHA256 mismatch` error. Any ideas?

Comment: Have also tried `brew upgrade` but get the same problem

Answer (score 1):

I notice that the expected value can be changed by running `brew edit azd` which opens up `vi`. You can then use that to change the expected value to the actual value.